# Angular - sending class as a parameter to http get

Tags: angular

I have a class similar to this:

```
  export class CodeTable {
  public tableId: number;       
  public connectionTable: number;                                       
  public connectionCode: number;    
  public code: number;          
  public translation: string = "";
  public price: number = 0;     
  public picture!: any;
```

}

I have a variable based on this class
const parameterToServer: CodeTable = new CodeTable(1,2,0,0,"",0,null);
I need to send this variable to the server to get a list of records to display.
I have the following code I wrote but it does not work:

```
    const getUrl: string = environment.urlCodeTable ;
    var selectParams!: any;
    selectParams = JSON.stringify(parameterToServer);
    let queryParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: selectParams });
    return this.http.get<ServiceResponse>(getUrl,{params:selectParams}).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the value of `fromObject` in `HttpParams` constructor must be an object: in your code snippet you're assgning `selectParams`, which is a string. Moreover, the object must have an index signature as you can see from the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParamsOptions#fromObject). So to solve your issue:

- Add index signature to CodeTable class:

```
    export class CodeTable {
       [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
       ...
    }
```

- Assign `parameterToServer` to `fromObject` and `queryParams` to `params`:

```
      let queryParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: parameterToServer });
      return this.http.get<any>('/foo',{params:queryParams}).subscribe();
```

Here's a working example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz-starters-vkzivj.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I’m sorry maybe I did not understand or maybe I’m doing something totally wrong, but it still does not work.
I tried to simplify things and changed things a bit to make it simpler:
This is how my class looks like now – only one parameter:
export class TmpCodeTableLine {
    [param: string]: number; public tableId: number;
    constructor(id: number) { 
      this.tableId = id;
    }
  }

Comment: Here is how I call the HTTP method: `        var tmp: TmpCodeTableLine = new TmpCodeTableLine(1);
        let queryParams = new HttpParams({ fromObject: tmp });
        return this.http.put(environment.urlCodeTable,{params:queryParams});
`

Comment: Here is how my client looks like:
  public class TmpCodeTableLine
    {
        public int tableId { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public class ServiceResponse<T>
    {
        public T? Data { get; set; } //this is the actual data from the server.
        public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
        public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

        public ActionResult<TmpCodeTableLine> AddCodeTableLine (TmpCodeTableLine line) {
            var serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<TmpCodeTableLine>();
            serviceResponse.Data = line;
            serviceResponse.Success = true;
            serviceResponse.Message = "all is o.k.";
            return Ok(serviceResponse);
     }

Comment: When I try to run the HTTP.put method I get an error of 405 (Method Not Allowed).
This is not a CORS issue because when I disable CORS and execute the HTTP.put method I get a CORS error.

Comment: I just added a working stackblitz to my answer. The 405 response has nothing to do with Angular or http params: as the message clearly says, the PUT method is not allowed for the resourse you're asking. That's a server configuration.

Comment: Also note that `put` method on `HttpClient` has the request body as second parameter. So your line: `return this.http.put(environment.urlCodeTable,{params:queryParams}); ` is missing the body.